# Bootstrap button position at absolute bottom left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-position

I'm using Django as web framework and Bootstrap for nicer frontend rendering. I'm trying to place an "add" button on my page that should always be at the bottom left corner. From the users perspective it should stay fixed at the corner even when scrolling; and overlay any other content.

If possible, I'd like Bootstrap's built in functionality and avoid custom CSS (so far, I don't have any).

I don't quite get how to use bootstrap positioning described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#common-values).

This adds my button, but how can I configure its position? `class="position-absolute"` doesn't seem to do anything.

```html
<div class="position-absolute">
    <a href="{% url 'app:add' %}"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It can be possible that another code is affecting it. Can you create a reproducible demo for us to check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url 'app:add' %}" style="position:absolute;bottom:5px;left:5px;margin:0;padding:5px 3px;"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i></a>
```

Comment: What I needed in the end was `position: fixed;` not `absolute`. But your answered helped me get what I want.

Comment: I still don't get Bootstrap's positioning though: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#common-values

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample html code that keeps the button on left corner as fixed item.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Bootstrap Text Utilities</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Tittle</h1>
        <div class="fixed-bottom">
            <button class='btn btn-primary'>Fixed bottom</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: Please, do remember to include bootrap cdn links for these boostrap classes to work.

You could use below link to modify the class names and see the result:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGY1VBV2YVFP